# QR code tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, qr-code

I would like to track visitors sent to a website from different QR-codes. The QR-codes are unfortunately not created with google url builder. The problem, as I understand it, is that these visitors will only show as direct traffic to the different pages to where the Qr-codes points. Is there any good way to segment this traffic from other direct traffic to the same pages?

Comment: Depending on your use case segmenting by mobile users might be an approximation (usually people don't carry their desktop around to scan QR codes, however they might scan coupons at home). However there is no real way to get only visits from the QR codes - one url is pretty much like the other to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to:

- Create a unique (sub) domain like `qr.example.com/whatever`
- Create a unique get request like `example.com/whatever?from=qr`
- Assume that everyone visiting your site from a mobile, with no referrer header set scanned your QR.

That's about all you can do.